# No confirmation on Teams reactivation, error page produced

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I was on this page:

[image]

I wanted to see the detailed options on renewing, like whether I can pay monthly/annually, see pricing details, edit my credit card information, etc, so I clicked on "Re-activate your subscription".

I was then directed to this page:

[image]

"Huh," I thought, "I guess reactivation is broken? Better file a support request on meta."

And then this popped up on my phone:

[image]

I can tell you for certain that this was the last thing I was expecting when clicking that link. I have not once in my life seen a link like that lead directly to a charge on a credit card.

1. Can you please undo that charge for me?
2. That error page should probably be fixed.
3. Clicking that link should not immediately charge a credit card. Either change the link to a clear "Purchase" button with appropriate styling, or have it lead to an order confirmation page.

Comment: PM on Teams here. Thanks for calling this to my attention! This definitely is off. I'm digging in right now to see if I can figure out what's going on.

Comment: Jeez that was one expensive bug find.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This was a case of a feature getting exposed to the user well before it was supposed to. At the moment, we have an imperfect "contact customer support to reactivate your team" process and we are close to automating that.

That being said, this feature is very much so still in development and definitely was not supposed to be pushed live. We've rolled that back.

You're a very expensive bug finder and I'm both embarrassed and terribly sorry. **I've refunded your credit card and added a free month on your account (it now expires 8/12).**

By the next time you get to your "end date", I can assure you that you can click that button without a several hundred dollar consequence.

On a more personal note, thanks for being cool about this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick turnaround on this! You guys are the best. <3

Comment: *this feature is very much so still in development and definitely was not supposed to be pushed live* ... so Chance took a chance